# Managing GCP network endpoint groups with terraform

Tags: terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing

Is there a way to have terraform use a non-existent data source or perhaps somehow delay looking up a datasource?

I have a GCP GKE cluster and workload being deployed to it which creates network endpoint groups for me automatically. I need to refer to those network endpoint groups in my GCP load balancer backend config:

```
  backend {
    group           = data.google_compute_network_endpoint_group.app2-service-80-neg1.id
    balancing_mode  = "RATE"
    max_rate        = 100
    capacity_scaler = 1.0
  }
```

However, since I'm creating the initial infrastructure via terraform, the GKE workload doesn't exist yet which means the network endpoint groups also don't exist.

This seems like a chicken and egg scenario. I want to have my network endpoint groups created automatically via GKE, but I need to refer to an existing network endpoint group to create my load balancer backend. Not sure how to get around this and would be grateful is anyone has a way around this.

Comment: Is using an exported resource attribute like normal not possible here?

Comment: Sorry, not sure I'm following. Are you referring to something like this? https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform/resource-management/export

If so, then that won't help me in my situation because when I'm initially applying my terraform code for the first time, there isn't a NEG to reference yet.

Comment: So you'll be creating standalone NEGs in GKE and then attaching them to the load balancer?

Comment: My NEG's are created automatically when the GKE workload is created. The load balancer backend needs to refer to these NEG's through a datasource, but they don't exist yet when I'm initially applying the terraform. However, I just clued in that I can just as easily put a depends_on clause on my data sources so they won't attempt to be read until my terraform is being applied so that solves my issue!

Comment: Can you share the full Terraform code ? I think you should use a attribute of the GKE cluster and not a data source.